# Subclass discrimination (TYPE) using a class member in JPA/JPQL

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, jpql

I want to discriminate by type in a query, but what I want to discriminate is not the entity in the SELECT clause, but a member of it.

For example, instead of using TYPE like this:

```sql
SELECT p
FROM Project p
WHERE TYPE(p) = DesignProject OR TYPE(p) = QualityProject
```

I need to use it like this:

```sql
SELECT p
FROM Project p
WHERE TYPE(p.leader) = Architect OR TYPE(p.leader) = Engineer
```

`Architect` and `Engineer` are subclasses of `Leader` class.

I have already tried that, but I am getting this error:

`org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
   SELECT d
    FROM Project p join p.leader d
    WHERE TYPE(d) = Architect OR TYPE(d) = Engineer
```